# Need help on making a text stay still even though there's text on its left

Tags: html, css

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIJ9g.png)

As you can see when I added the planets Element or button, the "Solar System 18413" text doesn't align in the center even though I programmed it to be in the center.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yORUd.png)

And look what even happens when I add more text it just push the H1 text is there any fix to this?

```
h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
.navigation {
  float: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: table;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #dad9d9;
}

.planet {
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: flex;
}


    <div class="navigation">
      <a href="#planets" ; class="planet">Planets</a>
    </div>

    <h1>Solar System 18413</h1>
```

I expected it to be where the H1 text is in the center and the Button is on the left not conflicting with each other's position

Comment: Re edit: You see where it said "enter image description here" and you changed it to "Image". The prompt was to get you to **describe the image**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert `clear: both;` in your `h1` style like:

```
h1 {
 font-size: 50px;
 text-align: center;
 clear: both; /*ADDED THIS LINE!*/
}
```